# Rails - ActionMailer - How to send an attachment that you create?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In rails3 w ActionMailer, I want to send a .txt file attachment. The challenge is this txt file does not exist but rather I want to create the txt file given a large block of text that I have.

Possible? Ideas? Thanks

Comment: Hey! I wrote a blog post covering this in depth — [Rails ActionMailer attachments](https://railsnotesui.xyz/blog/rails-actionmailer-attachments).

Basically, in our mailer methods, we get access to an `attachments` hash. You can assign file blogs to that hash, like `attachments['file.xlsx'] = File.read(/path/to/file.xlsx)`

Answer (score 74, accepted):

It's described for files in the [API documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html) of ActionMailer::Base

```
class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def welcome(recipient)
    attachments['free_book.pdf'] = File.read('path/to/file.pdf')
    mail(:to => recipient, :subject => "New account information")
  end
end
```

But that doesn't have to be a File, it can be a string too. So you could do something like (I'm also using the longer Hash-based form where you can specify your own mimetype too, you can find documentation for this in [ActionMailer::Base#attachments](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html#method-i-attachments)):

```
class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def welcome(recipient)
    attachments['filename.jpg'] = {:mime_type => 'application/mymimetype',
                                   :content => some_string }
    mail(:to => recipient, :subject => "New account information")
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked, but the attachment is showing up at the top of the message. and not at the bottom, ideas?

Comment: Afraid not, that shouldn't happen I think. Maybe something to do with the mimetype of your attachment?

Comment: If you want your attachment to appear at the bottom instead of the top, try this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10787533/196918

Comment: Something gives me the jeebies about an API where you create the attachments but never add them to the mail... I wish the attachments were at least passed into the mail method call...

Comment: @Trejkaz Completely agree. It's strange because if you create a `Mail::Message` object, you can add attachments to it: `ActionMailer::Base.mail( from: ..., to: ... ).attachments['filename.jpg'] = some_string`

Comment: Is it possible to do something similar and attach html files?

Answer (score 4):

First the method to send email

```
class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
   def welcome(user, filename, path)
      attachments[filename] = File.read(path)
      mail(:to => user.email, :subject => "New account information")
   end
end
```

Call the method with the params

```
UserMailer.welcome(user, filename, path).deliver
```

Comment: I think this does not answer the real question: `The challenge is this txt file does not exist but rather I want to create the txt file given a large block of text that I have`.