# Rails - ActionMailer sometimes shows attachments before the email content?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

How can I make it so ActionMailer always shows attachments at the bottom of the message:
HTML, TXT, Attachments....

Problem is the attachment here is a text file:

```
----==_mimepart_4d8f976d6359a_4f0d15a519e35138763f4
Date: Sun, 27 Mar 2011 13:00:45 -0700
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment;
 filename=x00_129999.olk14message
Content-ID: <4d8f976d49c72_4f0d15a519e351387611f@railgun64.53331.mail>
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the code from inside your mailer?  I suspect I know what the problem might be.

Comment: @AnApprentice I have the same problem. Were you able to resolve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem, and in my case the solution was to swap the attachment and mail lines. First attach, then call mail.

Rails 3

**WRONG**

```
def pdf_email(email, subject, pdfname, pdfpath)
  mail(:to => email, :subject => subject)
  attachments[pdfname] = File.read(pdfpath)
end
```

**GOOD**

```
def pdf_email(email, subject, pdfname, pdfpath)
  attachments[pdfname] = File.read(pdfpath)
  mail(:to => email, :subject => subject)
end
```

Answer (score 6):

I know there is already an accepted answer, but switching the order of `attachments[]` and `mail()` didn't solve it for me. What is different about my situation is that I was trying to attach a text file attachment (.txt)

What works for me is setting the `content_type` and `parts_order` defaults for the mailer.

```
MyMailer < ActionMailer::Base

    default :from => "Awesome App <support@example.com>",
            :content_type => 'multipart/alternative',
            :parts_order => [ "text/html", "text/enriched", "text/plain", "application/pdf" ]

    def pdf_email(email, subject, pdfname, pdfpath)
      attachments[pdfname] = File.read(pdfpath)
      mail(:to => email, :subject => subject)
    end

    def txt_email(email, subject, filename, filebody)
      attachments[filename] = filebody
      mail(:to => email, :subject => subject)
    end
end
```

If you are trying to send an email in Rails 3 with a plain text file (.txt), trying adding `:content_type` and `parts_order` to your defaults so that the text file does not appear above the message in your email.

Comment: `parts_order` worked. though not necessarily put into `default` section. it can be argument for individual `mail(...)`

Answer (score 0):

this is rail 2.3 code (might be slightly different in rails3)

just move you text part before attachment

```
recipients  to@domain.com
from      me@domain.com
subject   "some subject"
content_type  "multipart/mixed"

part "text/plain" do |p|
  p.body = render_message 'my_message' #this is template file
end

attachment "application/octet-stream" do |a|
  a.body = File.read("some_file.jpg")
  a.filename = 'name.jpg'
end
```