# Sending 1 attachement, recipients reports 2 attachements (ATT0001.c added) - Rails 3, ActionMailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, attachment

To exchange data with another system we send the data as an email attachment to a dedicated address. The email is generated using ActionMailer v3.2.12.

The problem is that when the email arrives at its destination, a redundant attachment named ATT00001.c is a part of the email, in addition to the attachment we created. This causes issues with the import routine at the other end.

A big part of the problem is that we know almost nothing about how the email is being handled at the destination . We also dont know what type of email server is in use and dont have access to check what the email actually looks like when it arrives. We can send it to one of our own addresses and it looks fine there.

I know this is not a lot to go on, but perhaps one of you guys have seen these ATT00001-attachments being added to machine generated emails before.

config.action_mailer.smtp_settings

```
address: smtp.<mailprovider>.com
port: 587
domain: ourdomain.com
authentication: login
user_name: <removed>
password: <removed>
enable_starttls_auto: false
```

**Update:**
We've been able to obtain a copy of the problematic email and it shows the email body rendered after the attachment as an attachment of its own.
We've tried setting ActionMailer's `parts_order` to make sure the attachment is generated after the email body, it did not help.

**Update2:**
Sending to my gmail account and showing original raw data I get this.

**SENT MAIL**
in receipt response from recipient to the correct attachment (the autocreated one creates an error log entry)

```
(...) cut: to from and through email header information
 Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit


--
Date: Thu, 28 Feb 2013 12:15:23 +0100
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment;
 filename="thefile.mscons"
Content-ID: <512f3c4b6e875_a8f756dcc642fe@bjorns_arch.mail>

VU5BOisuPyAnVU5CK1VOT0M6Mys3MDgwMDAzNDExNzE2OjE0OlRJTUVSKzcw
... many more lines like this ...
ODAwMDUwNTEyMTc6MTQ6VElNRVIrMTMwMjI4OjEyMTUrUE9XRVNUMTMwMjI4

----
```

This is with `body nil` in actionmailer

Next is a RESPONSE from the recipient system, sent to my gmail. It's a receipt on the correct attachment (the extra attachement generates an error, flushing their system)

**RECEIVED MAIL**

```
(..) unintersting header stuff with addresses
Content-Disposition: attachment;
  filename="afilename.txt"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Type: Application/EDIFACT; charset="iso-8859-1"
Mime-Version: 1.0
Date: Sat, 16 Feb 2013 11:07:10 +0100
From: ediel@example.com
To: ***@gmail.com
Subject: thesubject
Message-ID: <511f5a53.850a700a.2fa0.2a0eSMTPIN_ADDED_BROKEN@mx.google.com>
X-TM-AS-Product-Ver: IMSS-7.0.0.6298-6.8.0.1017-19380.002
X-TM-AS-User-Approved-Sender: Yes
X-Greylist: Sender is SPF-compliant, not delayed by
milter-greylist-4.0 (isp-app27-vm.isp.example.com [213.239.116.46]);
Sat, 16 Feb 2013 11:07:11 +0100 (CET)
X-ExampleIKT-MailScanner-Information: Please contact the ISP for more information
X-ExampleIKT-MailScanner-ID: r1GA7BqD021150
X-ExampleIKT-MailScanner: Found to be clean
X-ExampleIKT-MailScanner-From: ediel@example.com
X-Spam-Status: No

VU5BOisuPyAnVU5CK1VOT0M6Mys3MDgwMDA1MDUxMjE3OjE0OlRJTUVSKzcwODAwMDM0MTE3MTY6
.. more..
pUSU1FUisxJ1VOVCszKzEnVU5aKzErMjAxMzAyMDAyNDg1Nzcn
```

something suspicious with the Content-Type? Is a new (empty) attachment generated from the stuff prior to `--` in the sent email?

Comment: What are you using to send the email,  post the relevant part of your smtp setup.  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    :address => '??????',

Comment: The configuration have been appended to OP

Comment: is that mail provider MS Exchange based?

Comment: No, there's no Exchange server involved at our end. Also, if it were, wouldnt we see the redundant attachment regardless of where the email was being sent?
There might be an Exchange server involved at the recipients end, I dont know that yet.

Comment: Googling ATT0001 returns tons of stuff about the attachment,  it all seems to be exchange related,  likely it's on THEIR end,  also lot's of it was MAC users complaining about the issue when sending attachments to Exchange ????

Comment: Yes, the issue may very well be Exchange related on their end, however they receive these emails from several source and we are the only ones triggering the problem.

Comment: My reading of http://support.microsoft.com/kb/969854 is that it *could* be an issue if there is an Exchange server on their end (that would make sense too, given you don't have an Exchange server and you aren't affected). There's instructions in that article on how to format the email so that Exchange Server plays nicely with it - do they help at all?

Comment: Yes, that is a helpful link. We'll see if making sure the body gets rendered first helps, right now it is being rendered after the attachment.

Comment: Update: Switching the order of attachmen/email-body did not help

Comment: related Q: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5453052/252799

Comment: Can you get one of the emails that is successful? For example, from their other sources?

Comment: That would be helpfull, but I dont think we'll be able to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our problem is solved, though unfortunately I cant say what caused the redundant attachment. We worked around it by sending a non-multipart email that contained only the attachment. This solution obviously wont work for people who need to send a multipart email.

Sending non-multipart email with an attachment in Rails is not straight forward. You cant use the attachment helper method and a blank body, you need to put the attachment content in the email body and manually specify the disposition.

```
class MailMan < ActionMailer::Base
  def test
    attachment_content = "my attachment"
    disposition = "attachment; filename=\"test.txt\""
    mail(body: attachment_content,  content_disposition: disposition)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is to do with **inline attachments** and Exchange server. Some clients, Apple Mail in particular allow you to add inline attachments, that is, a MIME attachment sandwiched in between text/body parts of an email. Exchange server expects that all attachments appear after any text portion of a mail.

Everything after the attachment in your mail gets treated as an attachment, so the body gets stuffed into a file and named as you reported it to be named. Seeing as you're using ActionMailer, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9517665/1520714) and possible [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10787533/1520714), which explains that you need to switch the order of the lines of code, and possibly play with some other settings.

Comment: @Shargoz already tried switching order and the answers you link to was a question linked by me in a comment.