# send an attachment in mail using mailer rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer

I have included given code

```
def send_help_enterprise
    p '-----------------'
    p params
    Mailer.help_enterprise_issue(params[:app], params[:version], params[:name], params[:description][:text])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js {
        render :layout => false
      }
    end
  end
```

and fetch parameters

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "app"=>"test", "version"=>"1.1", "name"=>"faltuz", "description"=>{"text"=>"dcdfwedfed"}, "remotipart_submitted"=>"true", "authenticity_token"=>"rAykheNgAcEZF/M36i+hkpMzs+X1QZA+56hFoXAdQfXyDkGQU7K441nDylKKvj4cuxs/bfJgg7SEM0k9Kr+IGQ==", "X-Requested-With"=>"IFrame", "X-Http-Accept"=>"text/javascript, application/javascript, application/ecmascript, application/x-ecmascript, */*; q=0.01", "file"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0xb483c5d4 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20150916-3796-okttg1.jpeg>, @original_filename="images1.jpeg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"images1.jpeg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">, "controller"=>"enterprises", "action"=>"send_help_enterprise"}
```

and in my mailer I have included given code

```
def help_enterprise_issue(app,version,name,description)
    @app = app
    @version = version
    @name = name
    @description = description
    @email = 'test@gmail.com'
    mail :to => @email,
         :subject => I18n.t('mailer.info.help_enterprise_issue')
  end
```

Please guide how I can attach file  in this mail I want to attach given file which I am fetching in params[:file].  Please help me out in solving this. Thanks in advance

Comment: look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5145870/rails-actionmailer-how-to-send-an-attachment-that-you-create

Answer (score 0):

use attachment attribute 
`attachments['file-name.pdf'] = File.read('file-name.pdf').`

```
def welcome(user)
  attachments['file-name.pdf'] = File.read('path/to/file-name.pdf')
  mail(:to => user, :subject => "Welcome!")
end
```

refer this (2.3) :
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html

Modify your code to this:

```
def send_help_enterprise
  p '-----------------'
  p params
  Mailer.help_enterprise_issue(params[:app], params[:version], params[:name], params[:description][:text], params[:file])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js {
      render :layout => false
    }
  end
end
```

in your mailer

```
def help_enterprise_issue(app,version,name,description,file)
  @app = app
  @version = version
  @name = name
  @description = description
  @email = 'test@gmail.com'
  attachments['attachment.extension'] = file
  mail :to => @email,
       :subject => I18n.t('mailer.info.help_enterprise_issue')
end
```

Thisshould work

Answer (score 0):

Based on http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html, you have to add `attachments['file-name.jpg'] = File.read('file-name.jpg')`. So, you can put in this method.

```
def help_enterprise_issue(app,version,name,description)
  attachments['file-name.jpg'] = File.read('file-name.jpg')
  @app = app
  @version = version
  @name = name
  @description = description
  @email = 'test@gmail.com'
  mail :to => @email,
     :subject => I18n.t('mailer.info.help_enterprise_issue')
end
```

I hope it can help you.